# Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.instabug.bug

Tags: android, android-studio

Merging Errors: Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.instabug.bug.view.reporting.ReportingContainerActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, this is not the appropriate format for asking a question. Please provide more background, what you are trying to do, show us some code, what error you are getting and where. Basically, from what I read here, you are missing a android:exported tag in your Activity tag

Comment: Update your version of Instabug, they [fixed this already](https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Android/issues/391) (if you haven't already...)

Answer (score 4):

In your manifest file(AndroidManifest.xml), add android:exported="true" inside your ReportingContainerActivity's activity tag.

Answer (score -1):

Look at my manifest and still the same problem

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="d2si.apps.planetepicking">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />





    <permission
        android:name="d2si.apps.planetepicking.permission.SCANNER_RESULT_RECEIVER"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <uses-permission android:name="d2si.apps.planetepicking.permission.SCANNER_RESULT_RECEIVER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:persistent="true"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_roundicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_roundicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:node="merge">




        <activity android:name=".interfaceuser.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.ConfigActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CF" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.CommandeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CMD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.Configuration"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CNF" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LG" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.AccueilActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACC" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.PreparationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme3"


            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="device.scanner.EVENT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>





        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.DisplayActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".interfaceuser.Demarrer_PrepActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```